# Fatal error: Class 'PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase' not found in *.php

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, phpunit

I am completely new to Seleniu, and am trying to set up PHPUnit with Selenium 2, following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zva_GETXimI

So far this is what I've done:

Installed PHPUnit using PHAR as instructed here https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/installation.html

Installed Selenium Server

Upgraded to PHP5.6 (but my Apache is still 2.22 instead of 2.4)

Installed PHPUnit_selenium package using Composer

Created a testLogin.php file:

```
<?php

class testLogin extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase{

    public function setUp()


    {
        $this->setHost('localhost');
        $this->setPort(4444);
        $this->setBrowser('firefox');
        $this->setBrowserUrl('http://localhost/Achievers');
    }

}
```

When I run testLogin.php using 'phpunit testLogin.php' I get an error:

Class 'PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase' not found in /home/osadmin/projects/Sel/testLogin.php on line 5

Since I am just starting out, I have no idea how to fix this. On googling the error, it shows to add this line to my php file:

```
require_once('PHPUnit/Extensions/Selenium2TestCase.php');
```

But I'm not sure how I can use this since there is no PHPUnit folder, just a file linked to the PHAR.

Could someone please shed some light on how to fix this issue?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

As per Ushakov's suggestion, I tried `/path/to/phpunit.phar testLogin.php`

But it gives the same error.

If I add this line to the testLogin.php: `require_once('/usr/local/bin/phpunit');`

and run `/path/to/phpunit.phar testLogin.php`

I get this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
PHP Notice:  Constant __PHPUNIT_PHAR__ already defined in /usr/local/bin/phpunit on line 18
PHP Notice:  Constant __PHPUNIT_PHAR_ROOT__ already defined in /usr/local/bin/phpunit on line 19
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class DeepCopy\DeepCopy in phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/myclabs-deep-copy/DeepCopy/DeepCopy.php on line 15
```

Comment: Did you tryed run `/path/to/phpunit.phar testLogin.php` ?

Comment: Tried it, same error. Posted some edit in the original question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved it by adding this line to the PHP file:

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

No tutorial I have seen mentions this, but it can be found in github projects

Comment: Yeah it didn't solve the issue. Showing this error: `Declaration of PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase::run(?PHPUnit\Framework\TestResult $result = NULL) must be compatible with PHPUnit\Framework\Test::run(?PHPUnit\Framework\TestResult $result = NULL): PHPUnit\Framework\TestResult in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/selenium/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-selenium/PHPUnit/Extensions/Selenium2TestCase.php on line 596`

Comment: this answer didn't solve it for me ..

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else coming late to the party - this worked for me:

```
class testLogin extends \PHPUnit\Extensions\Selenium2TestCase
```

(Using PHP 7.0.3 and installing Selenium package with Composer ).